# Ethernet device voltage protection

Tags: voltage, power, dc, ethernet, rj45

I am designing a system with multiple remote devices connected to a central hub, supplying low voltage DC power and RS-422 data. I plan on using RJ45 connectors, and am wondering if ethernet devices that accidentally get plugged into the 'Hub' would be damaged by low voltage DC across two of the RJ45 pins.
I believe ethernet devices have 'magnetics', would this protect against this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetics will protect the PC, network card, chips, everything behind them etc., but they won't necessarily protect themselves. If you provide + and - on the same **pair** then high-current will flow through the transformer on the other end (potentially damaging it).

You can decrease this risk by:

1. Add polymer fuses on your lines (if that is possible).
2. Make sure, that you don't provide voltage difference to a single wire pair (and assume that user's Ethernet wiring adheres to standards). Eg. provide +5V on pair 1 and GND on pair 2.

Comment: Also look at how passive PoE works (not 802.1af/at) which already meets these design characteristics.

Comment: Also check that your current requirements do not exceed the cat5 thin wires current capacity (about 350 mA per wire). PoE uses ~48V to mitigate this, but the lower the voltage, the less power you'll be able to provide.